# Best way to get all users for a set of user_details

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Consider the following case, where I have two tables `Users` and `UserDetails`

```
User
has_one :user_detail

UserDetail
belongs_to :user
```

I have case where i had to search on user_details and get back a result which is a collection of `user_details`. Now I want to get all relevant `user` records of this `user_details`.

One way I know is to pluck `user_id` from `user_details`  result, and search for this id in `User` model.

```
relevant_user_ids = user_details_search_result.pluck(:user_id)
User.where(id: relevant_user_ids)
```

Other way is

```
User.joins(:user_detail)
.where("user_details.search_column = ?",search_requirement).
```

I was wondering if the User table is huge, will joining user_details slow down things significantly?

Which one is better, is there any other way.

Comment: Is `UserDetail` just extra attributes for `User`? Why are they separate models?

Comment: yes it contains extra attributes for user, basically its has a lot of extra data.

Answer (score 1):

```
User.includes(:user_detail).where(user_details: {search_column: search_requirement})
```

is also an option. This could be faster than `.join` (your 2nd example) depending on the following subsequent queries. i.e. if you're going to access UserDetails attributes later, then includes is faster but you'll need potentially bigger memory or none at all for this as it will eager load all User and UserDetails records, versus if join which will only lazily load User records, but would will need to call additional DB queries if you're going to access UserDetail records afterwards.

I am not sure how fast `.pluck` works, but if you're concerned about memory, then your first example using pluck is I think the way to go.

Curiously, I tried running tests:

(SSD, SQLite, Rails 4.2)

Scenario 1 (Not calling associated record)

```
Post.destroy_all
User.destroy_all
time = {}

user = User.create!(name: 'foo')
5.times{ Post.create(title: 'hello', user: user) }

start_time = Time.now
1000.times do
  user_ids = User.where(name: 'foo').pluck(:id); nil
  posts = Post.where(user_id: user_ids); nil
  posts.each{|post| 100.times{ puts post.title } }; nil
end
time[:using_pluck] = (Time.now - start_time) / 1000

start_time = Time.now
1000.times do
  posts = Post.joins(:user).where(users: {name: 'foo'}); nil
  posts.each{|post| 100.times{ puts post.title } }; nil
end
time[:using_joins] = (Time.now - start_time) / 1000

start_time = Time.now
1000.times do
  posts = Post.joins(:user).where(users: {name: 'foo'}); nil
  posts.each{|post| 100.times{ puts post.title } }; nil
end
time[:using_includes] = (Time.now - start_time) / 1000

puts time.to_yaml
# ---
# :using_pluck:    0.002787939
# :using_joins:    0.0027696689999999998
# :using_includes: 0.0027880739999999998
```

Scenario 2 (Calling the associated record):

```
Post.destroy_all
User.destroy_all
time = {}

user = User.create!(name: 'foo')
5.times{ Post.create(title: 'hello', user: user) }

start_time = Time.now
1000.times do
  user_ids = User.where(name: 'foo').pluck(:id); nil
  posts = Post.where(user_id: user_ids); nil
  posts.each{|post| 100.times { puts post.user.name } }; nil
end
time[:using_pluck] = (Time.now - start_time) / 1000

start_time = Time.now
1000.times do
  posts = Post.joins(:user).where(users: {name: 'foo'}); nil
  posts.each{|post| 100.times { puts post.user.name } }; nil
end
time[:using_joins] = (Time.now - start_time) / 1000

start_time = Time.now
1000.times do
  posts = Post.includes(:user).where(users: {name: 'foo'}); nil
  posts.each{|post| 100.times { puts post.user.name } }; nil
end
time[:using_includes] = (Time.now - start_time) / 1000

puts time.to_yaml
# ---
# :using_pluck:    0.006066561
# :using_joins:    0.006919676
# :using_includes: 0.00473808
```

In Scenario 1 (not calling associated record), `.joins` is slightly (I thought it would be a lot) faster than `.includes` because in `.joins` it does not require to perform additional queries to fetch the associated records, while `.includes` still fetch the additional record regardless. However, in Scenario 2 (calling associated record), `.includes` is faster than `.joins` because the `.joins` perform additional queries to the DB to get the associated record, while `.includes` already eager loaded it, and thus is already in memory.

Comment: interesting comparison, memory is a consideration for me, I think il probably go with `joins`

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to try testing the memory allocation as well, but I couldn't find a good way to check the object's allocated memory.